# What are the consequences the different file structures for installed Python packages?

Tags: python, configuration, package

The packages installed in my `site-packages` directory are organized in a variety of ways. Some have (1) the form

- A directory named exactly like the package
- An egg-info file (named after the package and version)

while others (2) have

- A directory named exactly like the package
- An `egg-info` *directory* (named after the package and version)

and yet others (3) have

- Just an `egg` directory named after the package and version (and a corresponding entry in the `easy_install.pth` file).

What determines which of these approaches is taken? Is it a result of the tool or approach (e.g., from source vs. from binary) I used to install? Can each of these approaches be maintained by all tools (e.g. `easy_install` vs. `pip`) or are they incompatible with one another?

Comment: An egg-info file is merely the ZIP'd version of the egg-info directory.

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately correct one-best-way packaging was not present in Python for a long time. As a result, if you need direct access to your site-packages directory (I'm assuming you're using a virtualenv or providing access to a daemon process), you need to manually set your PATH variables.

All the information you require to package for `easy_install`, `pip`, `distutils`, `mod_wsgi` you can review in [The Hitchiker's Guide to Packaging](http://guide.python-distribute.org/)